# 980px wrap with 1px left & border + 2 footer same size right below it not aligning properly

Tags: css, layout, html, border, fixed

issue that I`m facing

Layout: 
on top of the page there's 980px width menu centered with fixed position, it stays when site is being scrolled down

both below divs are centered:

980px wrap with 1px left & right black border

right below it there's a footer with 982px width and it's not aligned properly - it's sticking 1px to the left

Can be seen here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
             box-sizing: border-box;
```

And set your widths to 980px;

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way to fix this is to remove this:

```
.home #footer {
  border: medium none;
}
```

And then to #footer add:

```
#footer {
 position: relative;
 left: 1px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you are looking for but I think your `#footer-facebook` bar is missing 2 pixels in `width` too.

I checked it another time, to me it looks like those div have different sizes, the one you are having an issue with is 982px while others are 980px.